# Bad image quality after scaling canvas

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, scale

I'm scaling my canvas to fit all devices screens,
but after scaling my Background and objects show pixely and blurry
How can i keep the scale but fix this problem?
Thanks for Help!
Code:
`public void draw(Canvas canvas)` `{ 
    final float scaleFactorX = getWidth()/(WIDTH*1.f);
    final float scaleFactorY = getHeight()/(HEIGHT*1.f);`

```
    if(canvas!=null) {
        final int savedState = canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        bg.draw(canvas);
        btn.draw(canvas);
        if(!dissapear) {
            player.draw(canvas);
        }
```

Comment: You should have the FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG (uses bilinear sampling rather than nearest neighbour) flag set so that the bitmaps are filtered to minimise any artifacts due to scaling. This will not completely solve the issue. You can either implement your own scaling on bitmaps at load using a better algorithm, or supply bitmaps from the server that best match the display resolution. The latter is the better option and ensures the best quality for all devices.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for the good info, is there any Example of this or an article i can see about this?! i'm not that expert with bitmaps :)